# Calling Windows 64 Dll with Python Ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to call a [SimpleMotionv2](https://github.com/GraniteDevices/SimpleMotionV2) library from python using ctypes, it appears to make the call, but it always returns -1 when I feed it a valid com port.

I've built the DLL and the function I'm trying to call seems exported properly:

[DLL Export Viewer Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB4x0.png)

Somehow I'm passing the COM port number incorrectly?  I'm on windows and its COM5...

The function I'm calling is [smOpenBus()](https://github.com/GraniteDevices/SimpleMotionV2/blob/9a099b81bc0552ebdcdb649ac393fb0ddfb8bab7/simplemotion.c#L227) and is listed here:

```
smbus smOpenBus( const char * devicename )
{
    int handle;

    //true on first call
    if(smInitialized==smfalse)
        smBusesInit();

    //find free handle
    for(handle=0;handle<SM_MAX_BUSES;handle++)
    {
        if(smBus[handle].opened==smfalse) break;//choose this
    }
    //all handles in use
    if(handle>=SM_MAX_BUSES) return -1;

    //open bus device
    smBus[handle].bdHandle=smBDOpen(devicename);
    if(smBus[handle].bdHandle==-1) return -1;

    //success
    strncpy( smBus[handle].busDeviceName, devicename, SM_BUSDEVICENAME_LEN );
    smBus[handle].busDeviceName[SM_BUSDEVICENAME_LEN-1]=0;//null terminate string
    smBus[handle].opened=smtrue;
    return handle;
}
```

And my Python code is:

```
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL(r'./SMv2_x64.dll')

dll.smOpenBus.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,
dll.smOpenBus.restype = ct.c_long

ret_val = dll.smOpenBus(b'COM24')
print(ret_val)
```

What on Earth am I doing wrong?

I've tried making the ptr of type c_wchar_p and c_char_p, adding NULL terminators and string and not...  I expect to get a COM port handle return and I get -1.

Comment: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546). *argtype**s***, and it should be a sequence.

Comment: Thanks for that CristiFati!  Great post.  Unfortunatly I'm still returning -1.  I've updated the code in the original post to be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

It’s *argtypes* (plural) and is a tuple. `c_char_p` is appropriate for C `char*`:

```
dll.smOpenBus.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, # comma makes a 1-tuple
```

Then pass a byte string:

```
ret_val = dll.smOpenBus(b'COM5')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Mark!  Unfortunately I am still returning -1...  I've updated the shortened code.

Comment: Show that the code works from C with the same parameter. There’s nothing else to change from the Python side.